# System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded when uploading files> 3MB

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-upload, upload

I have a upload functionality in my `C#` `MVC` application. When i am uploading the file below `3MB`, it uplaods succesfully but after `>3MB` is throwing

> `System.Web.HttpException`: Maximum request length exceeded error.

I've tried changing web.config and below is my current one but still no success.

```xml
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />

<security>
    <requestFiltering>

        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />

    </requestFiltering>

</security>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that web.config in the root of your website? Not one of the subfolders?

Comment: You did see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)?

Comment: Yes it is in the root of my website and i did see these solutions and tried all of them.

Comment: You're hosting this in IIS? In a 7.x version?

Comment: Right now i am tryin it on my local machine, but i'll be hosting it on IIS7

Comment: Can you try `requestValidationMode="4.0"` just to verify if that changes anything?

Comment: Hey Thanks Rene for pointing out, it seems i added the changes in views web config by mistake. Issue is fixed now

Comment: Okay, awesome ... you're not the first to make that mistake ... *whistles...*